# Speed up matlab code with backward multiplication using vectorization

Tags: performance, matlab, for-loop, gpu, vectorization

I need to decrease the runtime of the following piece of code written in Matlab :

```
dt = 0.001; dt05 = dt^0.5; length_t = 1.0e6;
%a: array containing length_t elements
y0 = [1.5 2.0 1.0];y = zeros(length_t,3);y(1,:) = y0;

for i = 1:length_t-1
     dy = f(y(i,:); %call to some function    
     y(i+1,1) =  y(i,1) + dt*dy(1) ; 
     y(i+1,2) =  y(1,2) + a(1:i)*(y(i:-1:1,2)-y(1,2))  + dt05*dy(2) ;
     y(i+1,3) =  y(1,3) + a(1:i)*(y(i:-1:1,3)-y(1,3))  + dt05*dy(3) ;
end
```

The slowest steps are the calculations of y(i+1,2) and y(i+1,3) (because they require all the previous y(:,2:3) values). How can I speed up this code by vectorization and/or using a GPU?

EDIT: a is given by

```
a(1) = 0.5; a (2:length_t) = cumprod( (1-((1+a(1))./(2:length_t))) )*a(1);
```

and f is some function like:

```
function dy = f(y)
  k12 = 1.0;  k02 = 2.0;
  dy(1) =  - k12*y(1)*y(2);
  dy(2) =    k12*y(1) - k02*y(2);
  dy(3) = (k12+k02)*(y(1)+y(2)+y(3));
  dy = [dy(1) dy(2) dy(3)];
end
```

Comment: A GPU (or parallel CPU for that matter) aren't going to help you much, since this code is recursive and thus needs to be called sequentially. The problem is basically that you're performing one **million** necessarily sequential iterations requiring multiplication of a matrix containing (at most) one million elements. That's just a very large number of operations (order `1e12`). I'm unsure much will help if the actual matrix multiplication is the slowest, since that's optimised to the max by The MathWorks.

Comment: You could leave out the `y(1,2:3) + ` and the `- y(1,2:3)` (you need to add it when calling `f` though) during the iteration. And then combine `y(i+1,2:3)` into one expression. But without knowledge about `a` (or `f`) I don't see much room for improvement.

Answer (score 1):

Note that I do **NOT** have DSP knowledge. I hope someone can write a better answer or correct mine.

If you can tolerate some approximations:

You can see that ratio `a(i+1)/a(i)` tends towards 1.  This means that you can calculate a*y exactly for the first N elements (N depending on your desired accuracy), then add N+1-th element to variable `AY` and decrease variable `AY` by a magic factor depending on `i`. That way you can save yourself a lot of multiplications at the cost of this AY being somewhat inaccurate estimate of the actual product.

Your `y(i,2)` would then be somewhat like (`csa = cumsum(a);`):

```
y(i,2) = a(1:N) * y(i:-1:i-N) + AY + dt05_thingy + (1-csa(i))*y(1,2); 
y(i,3) = ...
AY = AY*MF(i,N) + a(N)*y(i-N);
```

Magic factor would depend on N and perhaps also i. Precalculate `R=a(2:end)./a(1:end-1);` and use `MF(N, i>N) = R(N+(i-N)/2)` - so take the middle ratio for the elements you are approximating.